# GetLine within list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, monads

I want to build a matrix in a list comprehension. For each row I need to getLine and parse it out.

In short, I want to do something like this.

```
fun = [ getLine | y <- [0..4]]
```

If I run this function, instead of trying to getLine from command prompt for each row, I get an error for No Instance for (Show (IO String)) arising from a use of 'print'.

I get the error message, but how do I getLine within a list comprehension?

Comment: You just did use `getLine` within a list comprehension :P

Comment: Yeah, I really want to use list comprehension so I can get coordinates for a matrix I will build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you’d like to take a list of actions, evaluate each one in sequence, and return each result – `[IO a] -> IO [a]` – there’s [`sequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence):

```
fun = sequence [getLine | y <- [0..4]]
```

and this can be simplified to [`Control.Monad.replicateM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM):

```
fun = replicateM 5 getLine
```

Comment: The sequence does the trick, because I need to keep track of the index to turn the matrix cells into coordinates. Thanks!!

Comment: @mac10688 In that case you may find a number of other useful functions such as `mapM` or `forM`. For example, `fun = forM [0..4] $ \y -> do { print y; getLine }`